# How to override webpack config in sagui

Tags: webpack

I'm new with JavaScript frameworks and webpack.

**CONTEXT**

I'm developing a project with react and sagui. And I want to configure the deploy phase. Sagui's "dist" command creates 3 files (index.html, index-hash.js and index-hash.js.map) using webpack. That is my **sagui.config.js:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  pages: ['index'],
  javaScript: {
    transpileDependencies: [
      [...]
    ]
  },
  webpack: {
    plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __API__: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '"http://XXXXXX.production"' : '"http://localhost/"'
    })],
    babel: {
      babelrc: false,
      presets: ['sagui']
    }
  }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

With this configuration are beeing created the 3 files at the same level in the folder dist:

```
- src 
  - dist
    -- index.html
    -- index-hash.js
    -- index-hash.js.map
```

But I need to have it like that

```
- src 
  - dist
    -- index.html
    - assets
      -- index-hash.js
      -- index-hash.js.map
```

For this, I'm trying to override the webpack configuration (I don't know if that is the right way), but I don't manage to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if some has the same issue...

I have communicate with the creator of sagui and he means that it is better and much easier to make the folders on deploying than on creating the "dist" files.

Thanks